# Problem in rendering ejs template with Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

I am using Node.js together with Express and EJS.

Below is my code:

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var app = express();
var urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false });
var publicPath = path.resolve(__dirname, 'public');
app.use(express.static(publicPath));
//app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.get('/form_get.html', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/" + "form_get.html")
})

app.get('/process_get', (req, res) => {

    console.log(req.query.first_name);
    res.render(path.join(__dirname+'/views/thankyou.ejs'), { name: req.query.first_name});
    
})

var server = app.listen(3000, () => {
    
    var host = server.address().address;
    var port = server.address().port;
    console.log(`Example app listening at ${host}:${port}`);
})
```

My folder structure is below:

- mysql (folder)

  - node_modules (folder)

  - app4.js (file)
  - package.json (file)

  - public (folder, it contains form_get.html)
  - views (folder, it contains thankyou.ejs)

The problem is the failing to look up `thankyou.ejs` into the views folder.

I get the following error message:

> Error: Failed to lookup view "thankyou.ejs" in views directory
> ".../mysql/views"

What can be the problem?

Comment: Please provide your folder & file project structure ;-)

Answer (score 0):

When rendering an `ejs` file, you don't need to use an absolute path, as by default it will look inside `views` folder. Also, you don't need to specify the extension `.ejs`. You could do so:

```js
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var app = express();
var urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false });
var publicPath = path.resolve(__dirname, 'public');
app.use(express.static(publicPath));
//app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.get('/form_get.html', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/" + "form_get.html")
})

app.get('/process_get', (req, res) => {

    console.log(req.query.first_name);
    res.render('thankyou', { name: req.query.first_name});
    
})

var server = app.listen(3000, () => {
    
    var host = server.address().address;
    var port = server.address().port;
    console.log(`Example app listening at ${host}:${port}`);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

When You use `app.set('view engine', 'ejs');` It is important to note that `res.render()` will look in a `views` folder for the view.
In this case

---

I mirrored Your project and it works fine with couple tiny changes...

---

Project Folder and file structure.

[image]

---

**app.js**

```
var express = require("express");
var path = require("path");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");

var app = express();
var urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false });
var publicPath = path.resolve(__dirname, "public");
app.use(express.static(publicPath));
app.set("view engine", "ejs");

app.get("/form_get", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + "/" + "form_get.html");
});

app.get("/process_get", (req, res) => {
  res.render("thankyou");
});

var server = app.listen(3000, () => {
  var host = server.address().address;
  var port = server.address().port;
  console.log(`Example app listening at ${host}:http://localhost:${port}`);
});
```

---

Output:

http://localhost:3000/process_get (**thankyou.ejs**) file.

[image]

---

Output:

http://localhost:3000/form_get (**form_get.html**) file

[image]